MS Teams app for management of software development
Looking for an MS Teams App to manage software development. Something simple as there are only a few people that will use it (small team). Desired features:

Feature requests
Bug reporting/tracking
Status updates
Git integration would be nice (not GitHub, we have a private Git server)
Handle multiple types of projects - desktop (C++,C#,Java) and web (HTML/JS/CSS).

We are a small company and have just started using Teams.
